Calculate required speed for given time, distance and linear acceleration
How can I calculate the required max speed (v) to travel a given distance (d) in a given time (t) with linear acceleration and deacceleration (a)

v = Max speed in m/s
d = Distance to cover (m)
a = Acceleration/Deacceleration in m/s^2
t = Time to cover distance (s)

It's given that there is enough time to reach max speed.
Example:


By linear acceleration, do you mean constant jerk or constant acceleration? Does it start from rest? Does it instantly switch from accelerating to decelerating so it has zero velocity after travelling distance d? If any of these are true, or false, please add details to your question.

Constant acceleration and deceleration, starts from rest and has to stop at distance d. It will not switch from accelerating to decelerating, it will need to keep the max speed for some time to reach distance d.

The distance travelled is the area under the curve in your graph, so there isn't a unique max speed. You can have higher acceleration/deceleration and a lower max speed or the converse.

The acceleration is given and I want to calculate the required max speed to cover the distance in the given time.

Let $t_0$ be the time when the max speed $v$ is reached. Then the distance travelled is the are under the curve in your graph which is
$\frac{1}{2}t_0v$ + $\frac{1}{2}t_0v$ + (t - 2$t_0$)$v$ = (t - $t_0$)$v$ = $d$
Since the object begins at rest and the acceleration is constant
$at_0$ = $v$
Multiplying the first equation through by $a$ gives
$(at - v)v = ad$
$v^2 - atv + ad = 0$
$2v = at \pm \sqrt{(at)^2 - 4ad}$
It is given that there is enough time for the max speed to be reached, so
$t >= 2t_0$
so
$at >= 2at_0 = 2v$
Therefore,
$2v = at - \sqrt{(at)^2 - 4ad}$

Works great, thanks!

We can use d = ut +(at^2)/2 to find the required initial velocity.
Once we have the required initial velocity we can use v = u + at.
The final velocity will be the maximum velocity attained.

Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our quality standard policy. Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.
